# .PNG Alternative to .ICO Files MVC3 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, png, favicon

I would like to make a .png alternative favicon image for non-IE browsers to read but I don't know what dimensions it should be. I looked at the .ico file in Photoshop and there are several different several dimensions to choose from. Presumably, I would make it the largest dimension of all the favicons in the file but I don't want to presume anything.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.mydomain.com/content/favicon.png" />
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.mydomain.com/content/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the syntax `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>`, as long as you convert your favicon to a .ico format (I prefer to [use this site](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/) as it also converts 32 bit transparent .PNG files) then all modern browsers should support it.

Some browsers require you to close the browser down before they cache the icon, but they display eventually.

As for size, they're displayed at 16 x 16 pixels, though most converters (such as the one in the link above) will resize them if they're larger.

Hope this helps!